# sendto ignoring MSG_FASTOPEN flag

Tags: tcp, network-programming

Replacing a `connect()` call with a `sendto()` with `MSG_FASTOPEN` doesn't initiate a TCP Fast Open connection. There's no TCP option for fast open nor data in the SYN packet, it just does a regular TCP SYN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A socket must have the `TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT` option set on it for the `sendto()` call to honor `MSG_FASTOPEN`.

After the `socket()` call, enable `TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT`

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

const int yes = 1;

setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

This is because `sendto` was never required to return a failure for unrecognized options, so callers in old code might have been inadvertently setting the `MSG_FASTOPEN` bit by accident, resulting in erroneous double-writes. Setting `TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT` informs the kernel that your process is willing to attempt TCP fast-open.